# Grafana create plugin one editor for multiple values?

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I'm trying to make a Grafana plugin and I'm asking you all if is it possible to **make 1 customEditor with multiples options**, as I need to make a object with key/value to start my plugin visualisation on the panel.

I created a custom editor in SimplePanel.tsx as follow :

```
  .addCustomEditor({
    id: 'env',
    path: 'options',
    name: 'options',
    editor: SdkMap,
    settings: {
      target: 'map',
      key: '',
      region: 'eu',
      env: 'staging',
      osm: true,
      showAttribution: false,
      zonesEnabled: true,
      selectionDetailsEnabled: false,
      mapSelectorDisabled: false,
    },
```

Then, what I did in my custom component :

- I imported types from type.ts (export interface SdkInitOptions) that looks like the settings object just over.
- Then, in my component, I can reach that objects with **item**, located in component props by adding type to the component props by the following code

```
  type Props = StandardEditorProps<string, SdkInitOptions>;
  export const SdkMap = ({ item, value, onChange }: StandardEditorProps<Props>) => {
```

Then, I created all my selector options, depending on their values (that can be either string, boolean, or selector) and mapped all my UI grafana elements with this array.

```
<Collapse label="SDK Init Options" collapsible={true} isOpen={isOpen} onToggle={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
      <Select options={options[0].env} value={value} onChange={(selectableValue) => onChange(selectableValue as any)} />
      <Select
        options={options[0].region}
        value={value}
        onChange={(selectableValue) => {
          onChange(selectableValue.value as any);
        }}
      />
    </Collapse>
```

The issue I'm having here is that the **value** is the SAME for the whole component, and whenever I'm selecting a new value in another selector, it returns the current selected value in my SimplePanel, and will always assign the new value.

On the opposite, if I'm making another options edition with grafana UI, "addBooleanSwitch" for example, I get the values of the 2 options editor in a object.

Is there any way to have 1 component that return multiple options values as object for the main SimplePanel components ? Or I have to make one UI element for each options I want ?

Thanks by advance